# Build Failure: Compiling Storm with Maven

Tags: java, maven, compilation, package, apache-storm

I've been creating a storm topology and tested it with Eclipse, it's working. But now I'm testing it with a cluster, and when I package the jar it comes with this messages:

..................................................................

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Storm.Prova 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Storm.Prova ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ Storm.Prova ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ Storm.Prova ---
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.713s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 09 11:01:02 CEST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project Storm.Prova: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/src/main/java/Storm/practice/Storm/Prova/ProvaTopology.java:[101,28] error: incompatible types
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] could not parse error message:   required: int
[ERROR] found:    Integer
[ERROR] /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/src/main/java/Storm/practice/Storm/Prova/ProvaTopology.java:108: error: no suitable constructor found for Values(String,String,int,int)
[ERROR] _collector.emit(new Values(tuple.getString(0),tuple.getString(1),z,tam));// id));
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] constructor Values.Values() is not applicable
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR] /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/src/main/java/Storm/practice/Storm/Prova/ProvaTopology.java:[111,31] error: no suitable constructor found for Values(String,String,int,int)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] constructor Values.Values() is not applicable
[ERROR] (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
[ERROR] /home/amnor/Baixades/V0.10.0/workspace/Storm.Prova/src/main/java/Storm/practice/Storm/Prova/ProvaTopology.java:[115,30] error: no suitable constructor found for Values(String,String,int,int)
....
```

....................................................................

And a lot more, the weird thing is that it runs perfect on Eclipse and not showing any compiling error.

Any Idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Here is my POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Storm.practice</groupId>
  <artifactId>Storm.Prova</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Storm.Prova</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-redis</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>Storm.practice.Storm.Prova.ProvaTopology</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>  
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>Storm.practice.Storm.Prova</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>   
  </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could it be a different version of JDK? Or dependencies which has been added to Eclipse but not specify in the POM?

Comment: I think it's more possible the JDK, I'm going to check the versions. The pom has all dependencies, otherwise, it fails to run on eclipse too, I've tested it. Is it possible that I'm not adding such dependencies in the Jar file? If needed, I can add the pom file and the entire ERROR stack of maven. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Please post the source "ProvaTopology.java" and possibly the POM.xml

Comment: I can't post the source code, I'm doing this code for bussiness purposes, and, as I said, the code was working perfect on Eclipse, so the errors must be on the other end, I'll post the pom.xml.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got It, done with the eclipse maven engine, can't really address why it was failing, but now it's working. Thanks for your answers!